# Excel/GSpreadsheets: Returning value based on word lookup, contained in a cell, from a list

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

This is my data:

**Sheet1:**

```
   A                      B
PUMPKIN CAFE          (formula)
TESCO STORES 5555     (formula)
THE WINDSOR CASTLE    (formula)
TESCO STORES 2344     (formula)
THE WINDSOR CASTLE    (formula)
```

**Sheet2:**

```
   A                     B
CAFE                  Eating out
TESCO                 Eating in 
WINDSOR               Eating out
```

Now, my question is:

How can I, on Sheet1, create a formula that returns the correspondent value of ColumnB on Sheet2, based on whether ColumnA on Sheet1 contains any of the instances in ColumnA on Sheet2?

I've gone round in circles, from MATCH to ISERROR and SEARCH, but can't seem to crack it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first bit of data is in `Sheet1` and your second bit (from which you are looking up) is in `Sheet2`, the following will work:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,SUMPRODUCT((NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,Sheet1!A1))))*ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)))
```

The important bit is the `Sumproduct` formula. `Sumproduct` will compare rows of data for multiple criteria in each row. If all the criteria are true for a particular row, it will sum a value.

In this case the criteria is that `NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH()))` bit. That will return TRUE in the case that `SEARCH()` came back with something.

The `Sumproduct()` then adds up the row number using that `ROW()` formula where that criteria is true. Since there is only one row where it could be true, it only adds a single row.. so this works out.

The `INDEX()` formula then just fetches the information from column `B` for the row returned by the `Sumproduct`.

One Caveat.. if you have more than one match in `Sheet2` for a restaraunt location in `Sheet1`, then the rows in `sheet2` will be added and the return from Column `B` will be wrong.